# Register with facebook - Java server side authentication - Getting access token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

To get user details, facebook docs suggests making this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

When a user signs up using facebook's "Register plugin", how do I get this user access_token from the signed request. The latter contains a oauth_token, but I couldn't find documentation on how to obtain the access_token. I use ***java server side authentication*** technique (I don't use the javascript way..)

Specifically, the docs say:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
    &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
    &code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521436/489177) recommends passing a blank redirect uri. But where does the "CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK" come from in the REGISTRATION flow? I tried passing the oauth_token from the signed_request as the "code generated by facebook". But it fails verification.

Pointers will be be helpful. Thanks.

Note: I already have the "sign in with facebook" working & I know how to obtain the access_token in that flow. But I would expect a more straight forward way of doing that when the user registers using facebook.

Comment: No one? I thought this may be a simple scenario which many might have faced & solved...

Answer (score 1):

You may have solved your problem, but anyway I place my case;
You must set exactly the same value for the "redirect_uri" parameters for both **dialog/oauth** and **oauth/access_token** pages (and unfortunately, this is not stated clearly on Facebook documentation). In my case the URIs in question were:

- https:
  //www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=23902620775&**redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mydomain.com%2fMembership%2fLoginCheckFacebook**&scope=user_birthday,email
- https
  ://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=23902620775&**redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocal.www.mydomain.com%2fMembership%2fLoginCheckFacebook**&client_secret=80a34471e31e7afa0a7a7cd3cfc7&code=AQDsrevxH_Q3-NVts8VBThXCC0z6cCIhdnTMVCE9McsjJYLLy6ZKnlibmi8tWPcP...